# i want this img class to be a button that plays a hello.mp3 when you click it

Tags: javascript, html

I want an image to play a sound when you press it but

This is what I have done so far

```
<img class="bilde" src="https://bnetcmsus-a.akamaihd.net/cms/gallery/04K7223BD7AU1446613320846.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this if you can use HTML5.

```
<audio id="sound" src="hello.mp3"></audio>
<img onclick="document.getElementById('sound').play()" class="bilde" src="https://bnetcmsus-a.akamaihd.net/cms/gallery/04K7223BD7AU1446613320846.png">
```

Comment: I use this code a lot for someone  https://jsfiddle.net/d8m17gw1/   her is a live example http://www.pscompetitiveedge.com/contact.html